# iframe is not working in blogger blog

Tags: javascript, css, iframe, blogger

Hi i am using iframe full height in my blogger blog.

Used CSS is:

```
#iframe {
   height: 100%; 
   width: 100%; 
   display: block;
   border:0;
   margin:0;
   padding:0;
}
```

and Javascript is:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var height = window.innerHeight;

    $(document).ready( function(){
       $('iframe').css('height', height);
    } );
</script>
```

and HTML is:

```
<iframe id="iframe" src="http://mybloggertricks.com"></iframe>
```

I had tested this in Dreamviewer with the same above attributes it's working fine in IE also. But only in blogger it's not working in only IE browser. Please help me anybody on this problem Please Help.

see that blog here:
http://new-temp.blogspot.com/2012/12/my-blogger-tricks.html

Comment: `$('iframe').css('height', height)` where is the semi-colon `$('iframe').css('height', height);`

Answer (score 0):

Iframe to monitor his load, code like this:

```
 var height = window.innerHeight, iframe = $('iframe');
 iframe.load(function(){
     setTimeout(function(){
         iframe.css('height', height);
     }, 100);
 });
```

Comment: I have tried, it is ok.you can put the code added to the domread

Comment: window.innerHeight only belong to 'webkit' browser. you can change $(window).height();

Answer (score 0):

Here is a tool for adding blog iframes to blogger: http://www.makingdifferent.com/online-iframe-generator-tool-for-blogwebsite/

If that doesn't help. You might be able to use the below code as a guide. Just copy and paste entire code into a page or post of blogger to see a test of how the iframe expands 100% in height.

If you don't want the width to expand 100%, just change all width sections to match your desired width:

```
<style>
#inside-iframe {
height:100%;
width:100%;
position: fixed;
scroll: no;
top:0px;
left:0px;
padding:0px;
z-index:9999;
}

body {
width:100%; 
height:100%; 
}
html {
width:100%; 
height:100%; 
}
</style>

<div id="inside-iframe">
<object width="100%" height="100%"><embed src="http://mybloggertricks.com" width="100%" height="100%"></embed></object>
</div>
```